# Upload file with google drive from web service c# fail for base uri = null

Tags: c#, web-services, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have implemented a web service that is calling a class which uploads a pdf to a folder on Google Drive.  Then I request a list of the folders contents.

The problem is that if called with a main the pdf is uploaded and the list is done.

If it is the webservice that makes the call the list is done but the upload fails and I can see an exception in the response:

> the base uri is null.

If after the calling with the main I try to call with the web service in localhost (via SoapUi) also the webservice is be able to upload the pdf.

The class that implement the gdrive API is the same.

**The code i used to get service from gdrive is:**

```
var keyFilePath = @"c:\Progetti\pippo.p12";       
var serviceAccountEmail = "reportbatch@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"; 

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); 

var credential = new  ServiceAccountCredential(new
 ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
             {
                  Scopes = Scopes
              }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
              {
                  HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                 ApplicationName = _ApplicationName,
              });
```

The strange thing is that listing work, uploading not.
Seems something about permission, but where is the difference between the 2 calls?

I'm blocked for this reason, can anyone help me?

David

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am going to have a guess and say its permissions.   When you run it its running as you however when the web service runs it its running under the application pool that your web service is set up  with.  to start with I would make sure that the web service has access to the key file.

Then I would change the following line

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret",
X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

to

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I have seen the above cause issues on Azure and this fixed it might work for you as well.

Comment: thank you DalmTo for your quick answer.

I just solved.
the error base uri =null indeed was a  problem with some dll versions.

After unistall and reinstall Google drive APi everything works.
Remain weirds that running it with a main i have no problem.

Comment: Can you add an answer to this thread with your final solution, it will be great for tracking it down later on. Thanks!